# How do I disable sampling for Azure Function using Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I want to disable sampling for my Azure Function that uses Application insights. I have followed these docs but sampling is still enabled.

[Sampling in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling?tabs=net-core-new)

[How to configure monitoring for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-sampling)

In Application Insights I have used this query to determine the sampling rate:

```
dependencies
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| order by timestamp desc
```

Here is my host.json file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "default": "Information"
      },
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried disabling sampling in code:

```
var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
            {
                EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,
                InstrumentationKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("Telemetry:AppInsightsInstrumentationKey")
            };
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Adaptive sampling will be enabled for Azure functions by default as mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling?tabs=net-core-new#adaptive-sampling).***

[image]

Change the setting ***isEnabled*** to ***false*** as shown below:

[image]

you can also disable sampling by using below code in ConfigureServices method:

```cs
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
            aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
        }
    }
```

Run the below query to check if the sampling is disabled. `RetainedPercentage` should display 100% as shown below:

```
union requests,dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType
```

**Response:**
[image]

Check the below troubleshooting steps if helps to fix the issue:

1. Restart Azure Function once you update sampling settings in `host.json` file.
2. Also validate your code and check if sampling is enabled in the Application Insights SDK configuration.